ValueError using csv.reader() in PyCharm
I'm going through Harvards CS50 Python course, in todays lesson we were introduced to the csv library. I think my code and csv text file contain the exact same text as my instructor but I'm getting a ValueError when using csv.reader(), I'm assuming because of the extra comma in the first key value pair. I'm under the impression that this is exactly what the .reader() function is supposed to prevent? My PyCharm is running the most recent version of python available.
My csv file when opened in the text editor reads as follows:
Harry,Number Four, Privet Drive
Ron,The Burrow
Draco,Malfoy Manor

My code is as follows:
import csv

students = []
with open("students.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for name, home in reader:
        students.append({"name": name, "home": home})


for student in sorted(students, key=lambda student: student["name"]):
    print(f'{student["name"]} is from {student["home"]}')

I've obviously tried changing the first "home" value to a string, so I understand it can be fixed that way. I'm more-so confused why my csv.reader(file) isn't ignoring the second comma, aka its intended purpose.
The entire error message returns:
python csvtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Julie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/csvtest.py", line 10, in <module>
    for name,home in reader:
        ^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)


The first line of the file has 3 fields, you only have 2 variables. What variable is Privet Drive supposed to be assigned to?

If Number Four, Privet Drive is supposed to be one field, you need to put it in double quotes.

BTW, you can use csv.DictReader() so it will create dictionaries automatically.

Answer
reader is doing just what it should in this instance - it's separating out the values in each line at every comma it finds.
What you want it to do is separate the first item in each row from every other item in each row. One way to do that is as follows:
import csv

students = []
with open("ign_students.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for first, *rest in reader:
        students.append({"name": first, "home": "".join(rest)})


for student in sorted(students, key=lambda student: student["name"]):
    print(f'{student["name"]} is from {student["home"]}')

This produces:
Draco is from Malfoy Manor
Harry is from Number Four  Privet Drive
Ron is from The Burrow

Explanation
reader is simply a list of lists. In your case, reader contains:
['Harry', 'Number Four', ' Privet Drive']
['Ron', 'The Burrow']    
['Draco', 'Malfoy Manor']

When you try
for name, home in reader:

You are trying to assign each item in a list containing three items (i.e. ['Harry', 'Number Four', ' Privet Drive'] to just two variables (i.e. name, home). Naturally, Python balks at this and throws an error.
In the rewritten code above, for first, *rest in reader: unpacks the list of a possibly arbitrary length - n items - into a tuple of just two items, the first item, assigned to first and a list of all the other items, assigned to rest.
Then, when constructing the dictionary to append to your students list, the value of the variable first is assigned to the key name, and a new string, obtained by stringing together all the contents of rest, is assigned to the key home.
